# ASP.net Server button mouseover effect

Tags: asp.net, css

Look at the reply and contact buttons @ http://forums.asp.net/t/1292579.aspx

how would I get that effect to my buttons (Dont need the icons, just the blue color, borders and a mouse over effect)

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well those buttons are really just hyperlinks with spans inside them. You can achieve the same effect by using LinkButtons and CSS styling using the border style and the :hover pseudo class.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="link1" runat="server" CssClass="button" />

a.button
{
   border: 2px solid white;
}

a.button:hover
{
   border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give your buttons a CSS class then add CSS styling accordingly.

So if you have a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="myCssClass" />
```

You would have the following script in your header:

```
<style type="text/css">

.myCssClass { // PUT YOUR CSS HEERE }

</style>
```